# Extract values from "media" array

Tags: json, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

I made and fql query and saved it into an array

```
$resultposts = $facebook->api(array('method' => 'fql.query',
   'query' =>  $fqlQueryposts));
```

To extract the name value I use this:

```
echo $resultposts['first_name'];
```

But I have problems with "media" array, that it's into "attachment" array. This is the structure: `$resultposts>attachment>media>`

I should extract "type", "src" and "href" values from "media" array.

I tried in this way:

```
$resultposts['attachment']['media']['type'];
```

But it doesn't work. The error is "undefined index: type".

What can I do? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This post is a little old but as I stumbled upon it while searching for the very same question and found the answer I'll share it for others.

Using PHP SDK (3.11)

```
$attachment = $facebook->api(array('method' => 'fql.query', 'query' => 'SELECT attachment FROM stream WHERE post_id = "'.$poid.'"'));

foreach($attachment as $attach)
{
    foreach($attach as $i => $o)
    {
        echo $o['name'];

        foreach($o['media'] as $t => $y)
        {
            echo $y['type'];
        }
    }
}
```